# How do i use R to input a number of grouping values and recieve an output of observations in a 8x6 grid?

Tags: r, input, output

I'm a newbie to the world of coding/programming. Loving the challenge so far but I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

I'm attempting to automate genotyping preparation for my job as a lab technician.

---

Unnecessary background:

I take care of a colony of 500-600 mice with 40-50 given genotype constructs at any given time.
Whenever I get new litters (depending on the genotype of the parents) I have to extract DNA and confirm the genotype of the offspring. 
The task and the challenge of trouble-shooting the process were fun at first but it's getting very mundane and repetitive now. 
So I've started using R to automate certain parts of my job.

TL/DR: My job is getting repetitive, I want R to help out with that.

---

So, in essence, I have an archive of mice as follows. I grouped them by the temperature requirements for the genotyping process and by the number of times I need to genotype the DNA samples.

```
Mouse ID  Genotype   Gender  Age       Litter_ID   PCR_Temp  Rxns
ZDP658    zDC.Cre       F    4.9        B23844-1      Z        1
ZDP659    zDC.Cre       F    4.9        B23844-1      Z        1
ZDP631    Villin.Cre    F    4.9        B23745-2      Y        1
ZDP575    K14.CreER     M    5.3        B23744-2      Z        1
ZDO931    K14.CreER     M    8.6        B23744-1      Z        1
ZDO932    K14.CreER     M    8.6        B23744-1      Z        1
ZDO933    K14.CreER     M    8.6        B23744-1      Z        1
ZDQ31     Rosa.TSLP     M    3.4        B23701-2      Z        2
ZDQ32     Rosa.TSLP     M    3.4        B23701-2      Z        2
```

My goal is to receive an output of the individual Mouse_ID's in an 8x6 grid grouped by their "PCR_Temps" and multiplied by their "Rxns" in a zigzag order if possible with two extra spaces per genotype group.

My vision of the output is as follows. I would want to input the Litter_ID of the litters that need genotyping and receive the following.

[image: PCR Prep]

The honeycomb structure is not necessary. A simple rectangular grid works perfectly fine. The same goes for the zigzag format. Both of those aspects of the output format would be nice but aren't a requirement.

Every group of genotypes would need one space for positive control samples and one space for Wild type/Neg control samples. The genotypes that have a value of "2" or more would be repeated as many times as their "Rxns" value states.

I'm sorry if this question is too dense to follow or code for. I have so far been working with `dplyr` and `ggplot` to manipulate and visualize my mouse archives but this particular problem has me at a loss.

If anyone could even point me in the direction of a package that could get me started I would really appreciate it.

So far I have tried some combinations of `dplyr` and `purrr` with no success. I have thought of ways to use for loops but have come up empty.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: I have some points of clarification. Do the temperatures need to be separated by vertical space or does your thermocycler gradient horizontally also? Does there need to be a minimum number of rows between temperatures?

Comment: The different temperatures would need to be separated into a different grid. Unfortunately the thermocyler can only operate at a given annealing temperature. Even though i have played around with gradient and touchdown temperature protocols that allow for variability. I have found that some samples just need to be at a very specific temperature that doesn't work for most other samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with the help of `dplyr`, `grid` and `gridExtra`.

Please excuse the hot mess that is my variable naming convention.

Your data was not complex enough to make a good system, so I generated some random data. Find that at the very end.

First, lets define our litters and filter the mouse data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

geno.litters <- c("B23701-2", "B23744-1", "B23844-1","B23944-1")
mice <- data %>% 
            filter(Litter_ID %in% geno.litters) %>%
            arrange(Litter_ID,MouseID) %>%
            split(.,.$PCR_Temp)
```

`mice` is now a list of the mice split into plates by PCR temperature.

Let's define a custom function to add positive and negative controls and duplicate rows for those genotypes that need duplicates. We can apply that function to every list element with `lapply`.

```
addControlSlots <- function(x){
  genotypes <- unique(x$Genotype)
  genotype.dfs <- list()
  for ( i in seq_along(genotypes)){
    litter.mice <- x[x$Genotype == genotypes[i],]
    litter <- litter.mice[1,"Litter_ID"]
    Temp <- litter.mice[1,"PCR_Temp"]
    litter.mice <- rbind(litter.mice,litter.mice[litter.mice$Rxns == 2,])
    litter.mice <- litter.mice[order(litter.mice$MouseID),]
    control.rows <- data.frame(Litter_ID = litter, MouseID = c("PosCont","NegCont"),Gender = NA,Genotype = genotypes[i], PCR_Temp = Temp, Rxns = 1)
    genotype.dfs[[i]] <- rbind(litter.mice,control.rows)
  }
do.call(rbind,genotype.dfs)
}

processed.temps <- lapply(mice,addControlSlots)
processed.temps[[2]]
#$Z
#    Litter_ID MouseID Gender  Genotype PCR_Temp Rxns
#1    B23701-2   ZO960      F   zDC.Cre        Z    1
#2    B23701-2   ZP810      F   zDC.Cre        Z    1
#3    B23701-2   ZP992      M   zDC.Cre        Z    1
#4    B23701-2 PosCont   <NA>   zDC.Cre        Z    1
#5    B23701-2 NegCont   <NA>   zDC.Cre        Z    1
#...15 more rows
```

We now have controls after every genotype.

Now let's define a function to fill in the PCR plate. And again apply it to the list.

```
makePCRPlate <- function(x){
  mouse.vector <- as.character(x$MouseID)
  plate.vector <- rep(NA,6*8)
  plate.vector[1:length(mouse.vector)] <- mouse.vector
  wide <- matrix(plate.vector,nrow=2,byrow = FALSE)
  rbind(wide[,1:8],wide[,9:16],wide[,17:24])
} 

pcr.plates <- lapply(processed.temps,makePCRPlate)
pcr.plates[[2]]
#     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]    [,5]    [,6]    [,7]    [,8]   
#[1,] "ZO960"   "ZP992"   "NegCont" "ZO214" "ZP333" "ZP455" "ZP478" "ZQ130"
#[2,] "ZP810"   "PosCont" "ZO214"   "ZP333" "ZP455" "ZP478" "ZQ130" "ZQ875"
#[3,] "ZQ875"   "NegCont" NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
#[4,] "PosCont" NA        NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
#[5,] NA        NA        NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA     
#[6,] NA        NA        NA        NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

We can see that the samples have been filled in in the zig-zag pattern.

Now let's use `grid` to make a `.pdf` file with the layouts.

```
pdf("MyPCRPlates.pdf")
for(i in seq_along(pcr.plates)){
  grid.newpage()
  grid.table(pcr.plates[[i]])
  grid.text(paste0("PCR Temp ",names(pcr.plates)[i]),y = unit(0.9,"npc"))
}
dev.off()
```

[image]

The `.pdf` file should have a page for each temperature.

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
data1 <- data.frame("MouseID" = paste0("Z",sample(c("O","P","Q"),size = 50,replace = TRUE),round(runif(50,1,999))),
Litter_ID = sample(c("B23701-2", "B23744-1", "B23744-2", "B23745-2", "B23844-1","B23944-1", "B23944-2", "B23951-1"),size=50, replace = TRUE),
Gender = sample(c("F","M"), size = 50, replace = TRUE))

data2 <- data.frame(Genotype = c("zDC.Cre","Villin.Cre","Villin.Cre","zDC.Cre","K14.CreER","Rosa.TSLP","Rosa.TSLP","K14.CreER"), 
                    Litter_ID = c("B23701-2", "B23744-1", "B23744-2", "B23745-2", "B23844-1","B23944-1", "B23944-2", "B23951-1"),
                    PCR_Temp = c("Z","Y","Y","Z","Y","Z","Z","Y"),
                    Rxns = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1))
data <- merge(data1,data2)
data
#   Litter_ID MouseID Gender   Genotype PCR_Temp Rxns
#1   B23701-2   ZP810      F    zDC.Cre        Z    1
#2   B23701-2   ZP992      M    zDC.Cre        Z    1
#3   B23701-2   ZO960      F    zDC.Cre        Z    1
#4   B23744-1   ZO122      F Villin.Cre        Y    1
#5   B23744-1   ZQ259      F Villin.Cre        Y    1
#... 45 more rows
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me with this. I would surely have given up before i arrived at where you led me.

Comment: I'm just glad you at least found the answer.